# Make custom class of NSObject serializable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, serialization

I want a custom class based on NSObject to be serializable.
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182115/make-a-custom-class-serializable-in-objective-c-iphone) but want to ask some additional Qs.

1. Does `NSObject` implement `NSCoder`?
2. I also want to ask if I can serialize an array of some objects of this custom class that I want to be serializable. Does this require some special init?
3. I know that I should implement `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder`. Is it the variables in my custom object class that I should Encode/Decode there?

Answer (score 2):

- [NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't adopt the protocol [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). NSCoder is a class, and NSObject is the class from which all the other Cocoa classes are derived.
- Your class doesn't need to do anything special, in that case; If the array is an [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), or an [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html), then the array will take care of the objects it contains.
- Yes. For more details see [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide: Introduction](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).